# How do I print off a calendar currently in HTML table format?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services

I have a calendar I want to print off, see the following image;
[image]

I am using a HTML table and the colours are set by background-color.

In order to print off background colours in IE you have to make a setting in the Advanced Settings to do this. My manager does not like this solution, it means having to configure all PCs that use it.
So the question then is how else can I do this?
I have access to SSRS but I do not know how I would do this using that. Maybe another alternative is to download a colour image to populate the cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I can find is to insert an image of the colour instead. That is what I am doing now for want of a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

you can download a background colored image, or you can put an X in the cell instead of the color.